# 'mat-form-field' is not a known element - Angular 9 & Material 9.2.0

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9

Hi I am using angular 9 and my code is as follows:
**HTML component as *"post-create.component.html"*:**

```
<mat-mat-form-field>
  <textarea rows="6" [(ngModel)]="enteredValue"></textarea>
</mat-mat-form-field>
```

My **app.module.ts** file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/Card';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';



import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PostCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mean-course",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
{
  "name": "mean-course",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

If I correctly understand I'm missing somehow / somewhere the definition of the mat-... tags but I don't know where I need to put what kind of definition? Can someone enlighten me a little bit?

Comment: You have to import `MatFormFieldModule`. Please, read the [**`docs`**](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api).

Comment: and typo "mat-mat-form-field"

Answer (score 6):

You must add `MatFormFieldModule` to `AppModule`

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        MatFormFieldModule
    ]
})
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve... I have imported the MatFormFieldModule in the app.module.ts file and still, I am getting the error "This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatFormFieldModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy."

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late reply but I had same issue it got solved just by installing jquery and adding it in script. You need to do following steps:

1. typo mistake it will be "mat-form-field" instead of "mat-mat-form-field".
2. npm install jquery --save run this command.
3. add jquery "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" path, to angular.json file under "scripts":[].